# 'NoneType' object is not iterable in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to execute stored procedure without parameters and insert output into excel.

In SSMS this stored procedure runs fine.

But here it reruns an error `'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Interesting thing is simple `SELECT` statement works fine. But stored procedure gives me trouble.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
 #parameters:
server = 'MyServer'
db = 'MyDB'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};server='+server+';DATABASE='+ db+';Trusted_Connection=yes;')
sql = """
        execute Align_rsUnitedSpecPolicyDataFeed
"""
df = pd.read_sql(sql,conn)
df.to_excel(r"C:\UserName\DestinationFolder\Test.xlsx")
```

This it the error I got:

```
  TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-31-d769e9510d21> in <module>()
         15         execute Align_rsUnitedSpecPolicyDataFeed
         16 """
    ---> 17 df = pd.read_sql(sql,conn)
         18 df.shape
         19 #df.to_excel(r"C:\Users\Username\Test.xlsx")

    C:\Users\oserdyuk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in read_sql(sql, con, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, columns, chunksize)
        397             sql, index_col=index_col, params=params,
        398             coerce_float=coerce_float, parse_dates=parse_dates,
    --> 399             chunksize=chunksize)
        400 
        401     try:

    C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in read_query(self, sql, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, chunksize)
       1435         args = _convert_params(sql, params)
       1436         cursor = self.execute(*args)
    -> 1437         columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
       1438 
       1439         if chunksize is not None:

    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Looks like you are getting an empty result.  So there is no first element in col_desc.  So you need to check if col_desc is empty before doing anything.

Comment: Which line is giving you the error? Give us the full stack trace please!
Also what is df.shape before df.to_excel?

Comment: That looks like it is coming from within `pd.read_sql`. I am pretty sure the second argument to `pd.read_sql` requires a `sqlalchemy` engine object if you are working with anything other than `sqlite` (which it looks like you are)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga could you provide more details about that? So I should not use pyodbc and pandas at all in this case?

Comment: @Oleg according to the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.read_sql.html), that argument must be a `sqlalchemy` engine object  or a DBAPI2 object (which will only work for sqlite connections). This is what the documentation states, so I think that is a good bet as to what will work...